# How to create a list to select index?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have this code to check indexes in a file to see if they match, but to start off I am having trouble being able to select an index. What do I have to do in order to be able to do so, because at this moment it doesn't show the values as being in a list.

```
def checkOS():
    fid = open("C:/Python/NSRLOS.txt", 'r')
    fhand = open("C:/Python/sha_sub_hashes.out", 'r')
    sLine = fhand.readline()
    line = fid.readline()
    outdata = []
    print line
checkOS()
```

Right now it prints:

```
"190","Windows 2000","2000","609"
```

I only want it to print: (so `index[0]`)

```
190
```

And when I try `index[0]`, I just get `' " '`. So the first value in the whole string, I want a list to be able to select the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `line.split(",")` to split the line by the commas, then strip out the quotation marks by slicing the result.

Example:

```
>>> line = '"190","Windows 2000","2000","609"'
>>> sliced = line.split(',')
>>> print sliced
['"190"', '"Windows 2000"', '"2000"', '"609"']
>>> first_item = sliced[0][1:-1]
>>> print first_item
190
```

...and here's the whole thing, abstracted into a function:

```
def get_item(line, index):
    return line.split(',')[index][1:-1]
```

(This is assuming, of course, that all the items in the line are divided by commas, that they're all wrapped by quotation marks, that there's no spaces after the commas (although you could take care of that by doing `item.strip()` to remove whitespace).  It also fails if the quoted items contains commas, as noted in the comments.)

Comment: Fails for quoted strings which contain commas.

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval('[' + line + ']')`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) might be a good way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`[0]` applied to a string only returns the first character.

You want the first item of a comma-separated list. You could write your own parsing code, or you could use the `csv` module which already handles this.

```
import csv

def get_first_row(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf)
        try:
            row = incsv.next()
        except StopIteration:
            row = [None]
        return row

def checkOS():
    fid = get_first_row("C:/Python/NSRLOS.txt")[0]
    fhand = get_first_row("C:/Python/sha_sub_hashes.out")[0]
    print fid
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you try using `split()` to split each comma and return first value? Try this.

Answer (score 1):

[`csv.reader`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) would be a good start.

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

with open('file1.csv') as fid, open('file2.csv') as fhand:
    fidcsv = csv.reader(fid)
    fhandcsv = csv.reder(fhand)
    for row1, row2 in izip(fidcsv, fhandcsv):
        print row1, row2, row[1] # etc...
```

Using `csv.reader` will handle CSV formatted files better than pure str methods. The `izip` will read line1 then 2, then 3 etc.. from both files (it will stop at the shortest number of rows in the file though), then line2 from both files etc... (not sure if this is what you want though). row1 and row2 will end up being a list of columns, and then just index `if row1[0] == row2[0]:` or whatever logic you wish to use.