# Matching index values

Tags: python, list, indexing, matching

This is my current code.  I want to check the two values(lines) to check for matches in the files.

```
def checkOS():
    fid1 = open("C:/Python/NSRLOS.txt", 'r')
    fid2 = open("C:/Python/sha_sub_hashes.out", 'r')
    outdata = open("osMatches.txt", 'w')
    line1 = fid1.readline()
    line2 = fid2.readline()
    while(line1 and line2):
        xline= line1.split(',')[1]
        yline = line2.split("|")[3]
        zline = xline.replace('"','')
        if (yline == zline):
            outdata.append([yline , zline])
            print xline, zline

if __name__=="__main__":
    checkOS()
```

The only problem is I'm not sure what I've written does that, all the code before the if statement is just reformatting to be able to pull from the index of the line. What I want to know is if the statement I used works in that sense and is it efficient?  Then I want to output the equal values.
Here are some lines in the files:

```
file2:
"10","Amstrad 6128","Unknown","1006"
"100","Macintosh 9.0","8.5.1","67"
"101","Macintosh 9.0.4","na","67"
"102","Macintosh 9.1","9.1","67"
"103","Macintosh 9.2","9.2","67"
"104","Macintosh 9.2.2","9.2.2","67"
"105","Macintosh 9.x","9.X","67"
"106","Macintosh X","10","67"
"107","Macintosh7.5.3","7.5.3","67"
"108","NetWare","n/a","674"
"109","Novel Dos 7.0","7","609"
"11","Apple II+","Unknown","67"
"110","OS/2","Unknown","427"



file2:

    DD84270022E57F1850C8454FA432ADFF99588157B|index.docbook|2225|Redhat 7.3 (32bit)|Linux

D84270022E57F1850C8464F5432ADFF99588157B|index.docbook|2225|Redhat 8.0 (32bit)|Linux

26EEEB25D7005F9FF9EE05A8084C77242702FBAD|Localizable.strings|2142|Mac OS X 10.4|OSX

34DC3D728C34E32F090307F575254D57E53C53FF|SYSTEM|10747904|Windows 7 Home Premium (32bit)|Windows

279E5A766C88EEA5AB946A0AF8D0C4FC366B2AF9|totem.devhelp|21324|Linux Ubuntu Desktop 9.10 (32bit)|Linux

279E5A766C88EEA5AB964A0AF8D0C4FC366B2AF9|totem.devhelp|21324|Linux Ubuntu Desktop 9.10 (64bit)|Linux

B3D11390AB8683BBE443A415EDD91BFDFD482134|dslconfig.pyc|6246|Redhat 9.0 (32bit)|Linux
```

Now you probably won't find any immediate matches in these few lines, but I know that somewhere down the line there will be at least one match because I saw that while skimming through the files.

Comment: Can you give a sample line from each file that should be considered equivalent or not equivalent?

Comment: And the code will produce `AttributeError` inside `if`.

Comment: This is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398796/how-to-create-a-list-to-select-index/11399036#11399036

Comment: It actually doesn't produce an error it just, runs. Also I don't think it is infinite because of the while statement.

Comment: And also this one... so bit puzzled why we're getting these again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265796/finding-matches-in-two-files-and-outputting-them/11267152#11267152

Comment: Because they all show me how to parse and format my info, but not how to output the specific values which match.

Comment: `while` loop in this case is always `TRUE`, so it'll run infinitely, use `for-in` loop to loop through the files.

Comment: @Larson -- It is infinite *because of the while statement*.  You don't change `line1` or `line2` anywhere in your loop.  So, if the condition evaluates to True once, it will continue to evaluate to True for all eternity.

Comment: @Larson you might be confusing `while` loop of python with `while` loop of `C` or `PHP` here.

Comment: Thank you, Ashwini and mgilson, I misunderstood exactly how it was working in this case.

Comment: Might have been handier to request more information on existing answers so it's all in one place, instead of create new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're probably looking for something like this:

use `with()` it automatically closes the files for you.

```
def checkOS():
    with open("C:/Python/NSRLOS.txt") as fid1,open("C:/Python/sha_sub_hashes.out") as fid2,open("osMatches.txt", 'w') as outdata:
        for xline,yline in zip(fid1,fid2):  #zip fetches lines from both files one by one                                           
            xline= xline.split(',')[1]      #use itertools.izip instead of zip if you're on python 2.x
            yline = yline.split("|")[3]
            zline = xline.replace('"','')
            if yline == zline:                
                outdata.write("{0}{1}\n".format(yline , zline)) #use write to write the data back

if __name__=="__main__":
checkOS()
```

Comment: If using python 2.x, consider using `itertools.izip` to prevent reading both files into memory.